Grid Row Start Over than Grid Template Rows
please could help me,
i set
`.grid-parent {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}`

AND
.gird-child.class-push{
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: span 2;
    background: darkolivegreen;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 5;
    display: grid;
}

the issue is when .gird-child.class-push has grid-row-start = 4; the .gird-child.class-push take 2 rows however if grid-row-start = 5 or 6 or any nmber over tnah repeat value will take just 1 row knowing i want leave ***.grid-parent *** still automatic i don't want specify number of repeat
Let the grid parent take grid-template-rows with repeat automatic

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Even if you specify 4 explicit rows, implicit rows are still created when your code tells it too.
